# Animate View/Rect on creation?

Tags: android, android-animation

i have the following code in my onCreate method:

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Paint p = new Paint();
                    field = new Token[FIELDSIZE][FIELDSIZE];
                    for (int i =0; i < FIELDSIZE ; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < FIELDSIZE; j++) {
                            Token tmp = new Token(j, i, p, false, PlayActivity.this);
                            field[j][i] = tmp;
                            layout.addView(tmp);
                        }
                    }
```

it creates this:

[image]

But its just there wenn the activity comes up.
How can i animate it? Like one after an other fades/flys in or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give this a try:

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Paint p = new Paint();
                    field = new Token[FIELDSIZE][FIELDSIZE];
                    for (int i =0; i < FIELDSIZE ; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < FIELDSIZE; j++) {
                            Token tmp = new Token(j, i, p, false, PlayActivity.this);
                            field[j][i] = tmp;
                            // Make it invisible in the beginning
                            tmp.setAlpha(0);
                            layout.addView(tmp);
                            tmp.animate()
                                .alpha(1.0)
                                .setDuration(600)
                                .setStartDelay(100 + i * FIELDSIZE * 10 + j * 10);
                        }
                    }
```

You can play around with these values until they are good for you. You could also try setScaleX and setScaleY together like:

```
tmp.setScaleX(0);
tmp.setScaleY(0);
```

and then later:

```
tmp.animate()
   .scaleX(1.0)
   .scaleY(1.0)
   .setDuration(600)
   .setStartDelay(100 + i * FIELDSIZE * 10 + j * 10);
```

Comment: What if you add a `.start()` after `setStartDelay(...)`? Do you see only a white screen or the same blue tiles?

Comment: Maybe the animation is too fast. Try a higher `startDelay`, like:
`.setStartDelay(2000 + i * FIELDSIZE * 10 + j * 10);`

Comment: And if you remove the animate line it stays white?

Comment: Oh you overrided onDraw()? :) Well that's the problem then. You could change your onDraw to also take the alpha into account, so when you draw, you check for getAlpha() and then draw that color.

Comment: If I were you I would just add Views with the fized size, and just set a colored background.

Comment: You could use drawables for that (stroke). Don't convert you alpha to int, because that makes it either 0 or 1. It should stay a float.

Comment: Paint.setAlpha() then takes a number between 0 and 255 where 0 is solid and 255 full transparent. So to fix the transparency, you should have: `paint.setAlpha((int)(getAlpha() * 255.0))`

Comment: What if you try the scaleX and scaleY example?